# React Material-UI autocomplete show Add button when there are no results

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to find a way to show an "Add" button when there are no results.
Is there a way to be able to get an event when no options where found? I see that there is an noOptionsText prop but I can't seem to find a way to get triggered when there are no results.
Does anyone know if this is possible?

I'm using Material-UI v5-beta and React 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the **Creatable** `freesolo` mode of `Autocomplete`.
it's in their [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/).

Here's a link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/g3dbg) as well.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to be possible to have a button though right?

Comment: The important part here is to be able to detect if there are any options corresponding to the search. Once you know that, you can, for example, add a boolean that will show/hide the "Add" button. There's an example with checkboxes in the documentation. I bet you can add a button as well...

Comment: The documentation has an updated version for MUI5

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with this and detect when you have no elements to show and return whatever you need:

```
renderOption={(props, option) => <li {...props}>{option.name}</li>}
```